# InjectView in RoboFragment

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice

I want to inject some views from an xml layout to a RoboFragment but unfortunately I am getting Nullpointer Exception. Since RoboGuice (besides being a great DI framework) has very little documentation, I don't know if I can use `@ContentView(R.layout.fragmentlayout)` to annotate my RoboFragment. Is there something I should do instead? What I currently do is:

```
public class TestFragment extends RoboFragment {

    @InjectView(R.id.upBtn) private Button upBtn;   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
        RoboGuice.getInjector(getActivity()).injectMembers(this);
        upBtn.setSelected(false);   // <------ Null pointer here
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you took a look to these two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780769/android-roboguice-inject-views-on-fragment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289660/any-simple-examples-using-roboguice-with-fragments-in-android

Comment: Yes. The first one just points out that the injection happens during onViewCreated but I don't unsterstand how.
In the second one I also tried RoboGuice.getInjector(getActivity()).injectViewMembers(this);
but it didn't help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you look at the source for RoboFragment, you'll see

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    RoboGuice.getInjector(getActivity()).injectViewMembers(this);
}
```

If you insist on injecting manually, use `injectViewMembers()`. If you can delay touching the view until after `onViewCreated()`, then it will be set up for you.

Comment: Ok you are right. I didn't accept the answer all this time because I was still getting a null pointer, but for another reason (I was setting the button listener in onCreateView). I apologize for my retardness..

Comment: although @ContextView didn't work...do you maybe know if this is possible?

Comment: I don't think so. Looking at the source of of ContentView, RoboActivity, and ContentViewListener, it appears you're only going to be able to use @ContentView with RoboActivities. Fragments are inflated in their #onCreateView method as you did in the original question.

Answer (score -3):

You need to return view. After upBtn.setSelected(false);

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
    RoboGuice.getInjector(getActivity()).injectMembers(this);
    upBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(YOUR_ID); // Initialization
    upBtn.setSelected(false);   // <------ Null pointer here
 return view;
}
```

Comment: This won't solve `NullPointerException`. But you're right, OP has forgotten the return statement in their question (not in his real code).

Comment: No it doesn't work, sorry. The code actually included the return statement. If it was missing I would get a compilation error.

Comment: The problem is related to dependency injection (roboguice), not in the code itself. He asked how to inject `upBtn` view in a fragment. Recently I had the same problem and finished using `view.findById(...)` but I'm interested in a solution that involves `@ContentView(...)`.